# How to remove string "[xyz]" from filename with Regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have the filename `0154562A5BS16101[001]` in which I would like to remove the "[001]" to just leave `0154562A5BS16101`.

I have tried using the regex:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(filename, @"[]", string.Empty);
```

But it throws:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'parsing '[]' - Unterminated [] set.'
```

I feel like this is a pretty easy for Regex masters, but I don't have much experience with Regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `[` and `]` are *metacharacters* in regex language, you need to escape them. You also need to tell regex that you want to match everything up to the closing square bracket:

```
var output = Regex.Replace(filename, @"\[[^\]]*\]", string.Empty);
```

`\[` and `\]` at the ends are square brackets that you want to replace. The `[^\]]*` section in the middle matches any number of characters other than the closing square bracket.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/u4mykw)

Comment: That works an absolute tread. Thanks! I must read up more on regex.